# Woocommerce: не добавляется атрибут к продукту

Tags: woocommerce

Я делаю кастомный импорт продуктов. В начале скрипта я создаю глобальные атрибуты:

```php
private function createAttribute($attribute)
{
    $attributes = array_values(wc_get_attribute_taxonomy_labels());

    if (!in_array($attribute, $attributes)) {
        wc_create_attribute([
            'name' => $attribute,
            'slug' => IM_Helper::translit($attribute)
        ]);
    }
}
```

Далее я создаю продукт и добавляю к нему атрибуты:

```php
$attributes_array = array();
foreach ($this->properties as $property) {
    $attribute = $this->createAttribute($property);
    $attributes_array[] = $attribute;
}

$product->set_attributes($attributes_array);

$product->save();
```

```php
private function createAttribute($property)
{
    $attribute_id = wc_attribute_taxonomy_id_by_name($property['name']);
    $attribute = new WC_Product_Attribute();
    $attribute->set_id($attribute_id);
    $attribute->set_name( 'pa_'.$property['name'] );
    $attribute->set_visible( true );
    $attribute->set_variation( false );
    $attribute->set_options([$property['value']]);

    return $attribute;
}
```

После выполнения скрипта добавляются глобальные атрибуты, добавляются атрибуты продукта. Но значения атрибутов остаются пустыми. При повторном импорте, когда есть глобальные атрибуты, все работает хорошо.

Первый импорт

[image: global attribute]
[image: product attribute]

Повторный импорт

[image: global attribute]
[image: product attribute]

Answer (score 0):

После создания глобального атрибута его нужно зарегистрировать. Так как это происходит автоматически в начале создания страницы, глобальные атрибуты при повторной загрузке срабатывают.

```php
private function createAttribute($attribute)
{
    $attributes = array_values(wc_get_attribute_taxonomy_labels());

    if (!in_array($attribute, $attributes)) {
        wc_create_attribute([
            'name' => $attribute,
            'slug' => IM_Helper::translit($attribute)
        ]);
    }

    register_taxonomy( 'pa_'.IM_Helper::translit($attribute), 'product');
}
```